# Summarize a factor variable by combinations of second factor variable

Tags: r, summary

My data look like this

```
set.seed(89)
d <- data.frame(
  ID=seq(1, 100),
  Encounter=sample(c(1:50), 100, replace = TRUE), 
  EffortType=sample(c("A","B","C"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I consider the Encounter variable as a factor.

I would like to know the frequencies of the possible combinations of EffortType.

I would like the results to look something like this

```
EffortType      N
A               8
B               8
C               9
A,B             4
A,C             8
B,C             5
A,B,C           3
```

I would also like to then be able to subset the data by the EffortType combinations.  For example, I would end up with a subset for EffortType A,B that looks something like this

```
ID  Encounter    EffortType    
52  2            A
53  2            B
61  2            A
63  2            A
79  2            A
36  7            B
59  7            B
83  7            A
etc.
```

I did try to reshape the data such that I had separate variables for each level of EffortType using "mutate", and then tried to count up the instances of each combination, but am not doing this correctly as shown below.  I can't figure out how to "group" by encounter before doing the counting.

```
d = mutate(d, 
              A = ifelse(grepl("A", EffortType), T, F),
              B = ifelse(grepl("B", EffortType), T, F),
              C = ifelse(grepl("C", EffortType), T, F))

d = data.table(d)
d[, .N, by = c('Encounter', 'A', 'B', 'C')]
```

But I don't end up with the summary I'm hoping for.  Please help. Thx.

Comment: good idea to set.seed() before producing random data for reproducibility

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've added set.seed() and made the "wished for" results match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a separate table for encounter attributes:

```
library(data.table)
EncounterDT = d[, 
  .(tt = paste(sort(unique(EffortType)), collapse=" "))
, keyby=Encounter]

# count encounters by types
EncounterDT[, .N, keyby=tt][order(nchar(tt), tt)]

# subset d using a join
d[EncounterDT[tt == "A B", .(Encounter)], on=.(Encounter)]
```

If you have a strong preference for using a single table, though...

```
# add a repeating-value column
d[, tt := paste(sort(unique(EffortType)), collapse=" "), by=Encounter]

# count encounters by types
d[, uniqueN(Encounter), keyby=tt][order(nchar(tt), tt)]

# subset d based using the tt column
d[tt == "A B"]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this!  I'm trying to use data.tables more and so very much like this approach.

Comment: Can I trouble you with a related question?  I'd like to add a "Species" variable to d.  I would then like to list the species by encounter, but with separate columns by EffortTypes.  I tried d[, .(tt = paste(sort(unique(Species)), collapse=" ")), keyby=Encounter] and can't figure out how to split by EffortType.

Comment: So instead of having "tt", i would like to instead have "tA" and "tB" for example.

Comment: @heatherr Good question. I'd make another table at the Encounter-EffortType level: `res = d[, .(tt = paste(sort(unique(Species)), collapse=" ")), keyby=.(Encounter, EffortType)]`. To convert to "wide" form with the columns you mention, maybe something like `wres = dcast(res, Encounter ~ EffortType)` would work or to combine it with the other table...`EncounterDT[, (new_cols) := wres[, -1]]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer to your first question:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> d %>% arrange(Encounter) %>% 
    group_by(Encounter) %>% 
    distinct(EffortType) %>% 
    arrange(EffortType) %>% 
    summarize(Efforts=paste(EffortType,collapse=",")) %>% 
    group_by(Efforts) %>% tally()
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Efforts     n
  <chr>   <int>
1 A           6
2 A,B         7
3 A,B,C       6
4 A,C         9
5 B           6
6 B,C         5
7 C           4
```

If you save the above processing of `d` as a data frame called `z`, you can subset the data based on each effort combination, e.g. for the combination of `A` and `B` in `z$Efforts[2]`:

```
> d %>% filter(EffortType %in% unlist(strsplit(z$Efforts[2],split=",")))
   ID Encounter EffortType
1   1        43          B
2   2        15          B
3   3         8          B
4   4        36          A
5   6         2          B
6   7        50          A
```

Add a `%>% arrange(EffortType)` at the end if you want to sort by `EffortType`.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was successful with the first part.  I did then save the processed dataframe as "z", and then ran the last line of code, but sorted by Encounter instead.  I noticed that the results include some instance where an Encounter has only A or B alone, as well as Encounters with both A&B.

Comment: @heatherr Maybe try `setequal(EffortType, unlist(strsplit(z$Efforts[2],split=",")))` as the filter condition after `group_by(Encounter)`.